# Spring's DeferredResult not working with Spring-ws (SOAP)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap

We want to handle a soap request in spring-ws using DeferredResult. We cannot change the wsdl.

Below is the code snippet we tried:

```
@PayloadRoot(
namespace=NAMESPACE_URL,
localPart="ABC")
@ResponsePayload
Public CallPerson(@RequestPayload CallRequest,
@SoapHeader("{"+NAMESPACE_HEADER_URL+"}Credentials")SoapHeaderElementheaderDetails){

    DeferredData deferredData = new DeferredData();
    // Some other thread would call deferredData.setResult() to resume control & return
    return deferredData;
}

class DeferredData extends DeferredResult<String>
```

Here class DeferredData extends DeferredResult. We expected that this call would wait without completing because deferredData.setResult() is not called. But this did not happen as expected. The API call returns directly without waiting. I dont see any errors in the console.

I tried the same thing in a Spring REST controller and it worked fine.

We want the deferredData.setResult() to happen somewhere later. The expectation was that the SOAP call should have waited till setResult() was called.

Any pointer on how we can use a DeferredResult in a SOAP request?